# Flask WTF forms terminate when a SelectField is added to the template

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a wtf form in flask:

```
class CustomerForm(FlaskForm):
    customer_id = StringField('System ID')
    crm_id = IntegerField('ID', validators=[DataRequired()])
    customer_name = StringField('Customer Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    alias = StringField('Alias', validators=[DataRequired()])
    phone = StringField('Phone')
    address = StringField('Address')
    default_timezone = SelectField('Default Time Zone', validators=[DataRequired()],
        choices=pytz.common_timezones
    )

@customers_page.route('/customer/<customer_id>', methods=["GET"])
@customers_page.route('/customer/', defaults={'customer_id': '-1'}, methods=["GET"])
@flask_login.login_required
def customer_page(customer_id):
    form = CustomerForm()

    return render_template('customer.html', 
        form=form
    )
```

The template looks like:

```
{% extends "main.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="app-content">
    <h1>View/Edit/Delete Customer {{ customer.customer_id }}</h1>
    <form action="{{ url_for('customers_page.customer_save') }}" method="post">
        {{ form.crm_id(readonly=true) }}
        {{ form.customer_name }}
        {{ form.alias }}
        {{ form.phone }}
        {{ form.address }}
        {{ form.default_timezone }}

        {{ form.csrf_token }}
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

When I add the SelectField **form.default_timezone** to the template, browsing the page terminates the application with no errors, exceptions or debug messages. If I omit the SelectField it works fine! Any idea what's going wrong?

**UPDATE**

Just solved! It seems that you need to specify **choices** as an empty list or a list with the form [(a, b)] (list of tuples) to make it work. I changed the code to be like **choices=[(x, x) for x in pytz.common_timezones]** and it solves the problem.

Comment: Just solved! It seems that you need to specify <b>choices</b> as an empty list or a list with the form [(a, b)] (list of tuples) to make it work. I changed the code to be like <b>choices=[(x, x) for x in pytz.common_timezones]</b> and it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved! It seems that you need to specify **choices** as an empty list or a list with the form [(a, b)] (list of tuples) to make it work. I changed the code to be like

```
default_timezone = SelectField('Default Time Zone', validators=[DataRequired()], 
          choices=[(x, x) for x in pytz.common_timezones])
```

and it solves the problem.